# Le truc c'est que

Tags: expressions

Depuis quelques années, l'expression `Le truc c'est que` se popularise dramatiquement mais elle me semble un peu trop familière.

Quelle était l'expression équivalente au siècle passé et quels sont les moyens pour éviter de l'utliser à tout va ?

Un exemple:

> J'ai reçu tous les éléments de la machine, le truc c'est que j'ai oublié ma caisse à outils. Ce n'est pas grand chose mais du coup on ne peut plus avancer

Comment: `cependant` semble très bien remplacer l'expression dans ton cas avec un "mais" avant.

Comment: Ne serait-ce pas une expression où l'on fait une ellipse? Il me semble que sans l'ellipse on obtiendrait quelque chose comme: "ce qui pose problème (le truc) c'est que".

Comment: "se popularise dramatiquement" est un anglicisme, "se popularise beaucoup, nettement, de façon spectaculaire, etc."

Comment: Sauf s'il veut vraiment dire que c'est dramatique.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Effectivement mais [jiliagre](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109/jlliagre) à vu juste pour le coup.

Comment: @nowox Haha, je n'avais pas fait le rapprochement avec l'anglais et je pensais que tu voulais dire que c'était un drame.

Answer (score 3):

L'expression "*Le truc c'est que*" traduit une opposition. Il y a une myriade de substitutions possibles pour cette expression.

Si on resserre un peu plus la sémantique, en précisant un peu plus le type d'opposition exprimé, on peut dire qu'il s'agit d'un détail défaillant qui rend un ensemble non fonctionnel ou qui ne remplit pas son but.
Pour faire plus court : "J'ai reçu tous les éléments de la machine, le truc c'est que j'ai oublié ma caisse à outils. Ce n'est pas grand chose mais du coup on ne peut plus avancer".

Dans ce cas, parmi les propositions qui me semblent le plus appropriées, il y a :

- Sauf que
- Seulement
- Cependant